# Difference between Global object and local object [firebase]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, global-variables

I don't if I should ask this question or not but it's confusing me that why some tutors make `FirebaseFirestore` object **Global** and some **Local**. can anyone please elaborate between these two. Following is the code for your understanding.

PS: I know that Global is accessible by the whole class but Local are not.

**Global object of FirebaseFirestore:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     
        //Global object db.
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             
             //rest of the code.
      
        }
    }
```

**Local Object of FirebaseFirestore:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                //local object
                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to your use case. If you need to make Firebase request in multiple places in your app, a global object would save you the time and resources to reinitialize `FirebaseFirestore`. And if you only need to load data just once, or you rarely use it in other places, a local object would be fine.

Personaly I would just put it in global scope and use it anywhere i want without worrying about its scope

Comment: but will it affect if I make it global and use everywhere in my class?

Comment: you cant really make breaking changes to `FirebaseFirestore` object. A typical usecase of reading and updating data is fine